# How can I define this variable before arrays?

Tags: lua

I make a LUA script for my game with the Logitech Gaming Software but I struggle with one thing.

I just want to define the variable "var" BEFORE the arrays.

I have more than 50 arrays so I'm tired of scrolling down everytime I want to change this variable..

How can I do it ?

Here is a simplified version of my script.

> It works :

```
array1 = { "TRUE", 5, 4, 5, 5 }
array2 = { "FALSE", 6, 3, 8, 5 }
array3 = { "FALSE", 3, 2, 5, 3 }

var = array1

OutputLogMessage(var[1])
```

> It doesn't work :

```
var = array1

array1 = { "TRUE", 5, 4, 5, 5 }
array2 = { "FALSE", 6, 3, 8, 5 }
array3 = { "FALSE", 3, 2, 5, 3 }

OutputLogMessage(var[1])
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work the second way because `array1` doesn't exist at the moment when you copy it into `var` variable.

If you want to keep the code as it is now, i.e. creating arbitrarily named variables later, but specify the desired link upfront, you'll have to resolve assignment after you've created all the arrays. It could go like this:

```
var = "array1"

array1 = {blah-blah1}
array2 = {blah-blah2}
array2 = {blah-blah3}

-- this is where the var will be replaced with actual value
var = _G[var]
```

Comment: It works, thank you Vlad.

But is it possible to avoid the double quotes for var ?

Like this : var = array1

Comment: No. The construct `var = array1` means copying the value of variable `array1` into variable `var`. If the `array1` doesn't exist yet, then it will read `nil`, so won't do anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest your arrays into an other array.

```
var = 1

arrays = {
    { "TRUE", 5, 4, 5, 5 },    --array1
    { "FALSE", 6, 3, 8, 5 },   --array2
    { "FALSE", 3, 2, 5, 3 },   --array3
}

print(arrays[var][1]) -- do stuff with first item in arrays[1]
```

This can clean up the code a bit, it would also allow you to collapse the `arrays` definition, in an ide that has that feature, so you dont have to scroll through them.

---

Additionally if you need the key to be a string you can define `arrays` like this:

```
var = "array1" -- must have the quotes

arrays = {
    array1 = { "TRUE", 5, 4, 5, 5 },
    array2 = { "FALSE", 6, 3, 8, 5 },
    array3 = { "FALSE", 3, 2, 5, 3 },
}

print(arrays[var][1]) -- do stuff with first item in arrays[array1]
```

This method is going to produce a table as apposed to the other method with produces an array. There is a difference in efficiency in favor of the first method, which is something to keep in mind.

Comment: `> it would also allow you to collapse the arrays definition` not in the builtin editor of the logitech software though ;)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer valid point! amended that portion of the answer.

Comment: var must be an integer so ? In my script I prefer to use a string in order to choose the character's config

Comment: @Era you could nest the arrays and give them keys i have added that option to my answer.